# C++: Process 2d array elements in a diagonal fashion

Tags: c++, arrays, loops, nested, 2d

Let's say we have a two dimensional arrays, `arr[N][N]`, where `N` is a `constant integer`.
Assume that every element of `arr` is initialized.

How do I print the elements of `arr` antidiagonal-wise using nested for loops?

What I mean is:

- After first iteration of the outer-most loop, `arr[0][0]` will be printed
- After second iteration of the outer-most loop, `arr[0][1]` and `arr[1][0]` will be printed
- After third iteration of the outer-most loop, `arr[0][2]`, `arr[1][1]`, and `arr[2][0]` will be printed
- ...
- After the last iteration of the outer-most loop, `arr[N-1][N-1]` will be printed.

Thanks for your time!

Comment: lol it's true that the question kind of worded like a hw problem, but it's actually not ;)

Comment: JPEG's zigzag traversal?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sorry to everybody who wrote "The second half should be similar"... it's not.

Anyway, here you go:

```
// traverse array diagonally
int c, tmp, x;
for (c = N - 1; c > -N; c--) {
    tmp = N - abs(c) - 1;
    x = tmp;
    while (x >= 0) {
        if (c >= 0) {
            std::cout << arr[x][tmp - x] << ", ";
        }
        else {
            std::cout << arr[N - (tmp - x) - 1][(N-1)-x] << ", ";
        }
        --x;
    }
    std::cout << "\n";
}
```

Do you need this for a game or something?

[edit] looking at this again, I think my answer wasn't very nicely written. Here's a quick run through:

Let's pretend that N is 3.

What we need is an iteration over coordinate-combinations that looks like this:

```
(0, 0)
(1, 0), (0, 1)
(2, 0), (1, 1), (0, 2)
(2, 1), (1, 2)
(2, 2)
```

So first some placeholders:

```
int c,    // a counter, set by the outer loop
    tmp,  // for intermediate results
    x;    // the x-index into *arr* (*y* will be defined implicitly)
```

Now this outer loop

```
for (c = N - 1; c > -N; c--) {
```

makes *c* iterate over *{2, 1, 0, -1, 2}*.

The next step

```
    tmp = N - abs(c) - 1;
    x = tmp;
```

turns *{2, 1, 0, -1, -2}* into *{0, 1, 2, 1, 0}*, which are the lengths of the needed outputs at this step minus one (so they can be used as indices). We make two copies of this, *tmp* and *x*.

Now we count down from *x* to *0*:

```
    while (x >= 0) {
        ...
        --x;
    }
```

if we're on the upper-left half of *arr*, indicated by *c >= 0*, the x-indices into *arr* need to start at the diagonal and go down to zero *(0 to 0, 1 to 0 and 2 to 0)* , whereas the y-indices need to start at zero and go up to the diagonal *(0 to 0, 0 to 1 and 0 to 2)*:

```
        if (c >= 0) {
            std::cout << arr[x][tmp - x] << ", ";
        }
```

once we're on the lower-right half, the x-indices need to start at *N* and to down to the diagonal *(2 to 1 and 2 to 2)*, whereas the y-indices need to start at the diagonal and go up to *N (1 to 2 and 2 to 2)*:

```
        else {
            std::cout << arr[N - (tmp - x) - 1][(N-1)-x] << ", ";
        }
```

finally we just need a line-break at the end of each line:

```
    std::cout << "\n";
```

Savy? :-)

Comment: Thank you for giving me a complete answer ;). I need this because there is a nested for-loop that cannot be parallelized row-wise or column-wise because of data dependencies, so it can only be done antidiagonal-wise.

Comment: Ok? Sounds scary :-)

Well, if it works for you, can you click 'accept' please? Thanks!! :-)

Answer (score 2):

This will work for half the matrix.. the other half will be similar:

```
for (j = 0 ; j < N ; j++)
{
   for (i = 0 ; i <= j ; i ++)
   {
      printf("%d \n",a[i,j-i]);
   }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can notice that for any diagonal, 2 "adjacent" elements are given by `[x][y]` and `[x+1][y-1]`: that is, you take a diagonal step to the right and up.

So you can have a loop that sets the first cell of the diagonal. You only need to iterate through all values of `y`, starting at `[0][y]`, and then do this right-up step (diagonally) until you hit the top side or the right side. Then you will need to do the same by moving across from `[0][N-1]` to `[N-1][N-1]` to cover the second half.

Code follows:

```
for (int _y = 0; _y < N; _y++) {
    int x = 0, y = _y;
    while (x < N && y >= 0) {
        cout << arr[x][y];
        x++; y--;
    }

    cout << endl; // don't forget a newline
}
```

I am going to leave out the second half of the code, because it should be about the same.

Comment: +1 for explanation, even though I like the code in other answers better

Answer (score 1):

Here is a snippet of java code, but the algo is the same

```
for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
    for(int j = 0; j <= i; j++){
        System.out.print(a[j][i-j] + " ");
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks something like this:

```
for(row = 0; row < N; row++){  
   for(j = 0; j <= row; j++){  
      print Array[row - j][j];  
   }  
   newline;  
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is the solution for both halves of the matrix:

```
    //First half (including middle diagonal)
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j <= i; j++) {
            print array[j][i - j];
        }
        newline;
    }

    //Second half (excluding middle diagonal)
    for (int i = n - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        for (int j = 0; j < i; j++) {
            print array[n - i + j][n - j - 1];
        }
        newline;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here Is One Solution I think Its Helpful
R is Total Number of Row.

```
    void diagonalOrder(int arr[][COLS],int R)
    {

        for (int i = 0; i < R+COLS-1; i++)
        {
            int col;
            int row;
            i<COLS?col=i:col=(COLS-1);
            col>i?row=col-i:row=i-col;

            for(int j=col;j>=0 ;j--)
            {
                if(row<R)
                    cout<<arr[row][j]<<" ";
                row++;
            }
            cout<<endl;
        }
    }

ie.
const int ROWS = 4;
const int COLS = 3;

int arr[][COLS] = {{ 1, 2, 4 },
                        { 3, 5, 7},
                        { 6, 8, 10},
                        { 9, 11, 12}
                    };
    diagonalOrder(arr,ROWS);

Output
----------
1
2 3
4 5 6
7 8 9
10 11
12

------------------------------------------------------
const int ROWS = 8;
const int COLS = 3;

    int arr8[][COLS] = {{ 1, 2, 4 },
                        { 3, 5, 7 },
                        { 6, 8, 10 },
                        { 9, 11, 13 },
                        { 12, 14, 16},
                        { 15 ,17, 19},
                        { 18 ,20, 22},
                        { 21, 23, 24}

                    };

    cout<<"\n\n8*3 Matrix"<<endl<<endl;
    diagonalOrder(arr8,8);

--------------------------------------------------------------
Output
--------------------------------------------------------------
1
2 3
4 5 6
7 8 9
10 11 12
13 14 15
16 17 18
19 20 21
22 23
24
-----------------------------------------

    int arr[][COLS] = {{ 1, 2, 4 ,20},
                        { 3, 5, 7,20},
                        { 6, 8, 10,20},
                        { 9, 11, 12,20}
                    };
-------------------------------------------------------------
Output
-------------------------------------------------------------

1
2 3
4 5 6
20 7 8 9
20 10 11
20 12
20


You can work with n*n Matrix ..
```